# FontRenderer cache maxed out

Tags: android, android-widget

I am in the process of trying to pin down the cause of an intermittently laggy UI in our app and have gone through the various steps outlined [by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/). I have narrowed it down to calls to `android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawDisplayList` and its corresponding `android.view.GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList` which tells me that it has to do with my views. I know I have a lot of views (213) and I am working to reduce it but when I profiled the GPU rendering, I noticed in the caches section that the memory usage of the FontRenderer is at maximum while other memory consumption is moderate. What exactly is this cache responsible for and could it being full be leading to some of the intermittent lag? I have included that section below. I should not too that this issue becomes significantly more pronounced on a Nexus 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal for the font cache to be maxed out. This would not be the cause of your slowdown.

Comment: Just what I needed to know, thanks. Probably just the view count then.

Comment: Make sure you're not using Canva.saveLayer and Canvas.saveLayerAlpha. These operations can be very expensive.

Comment: What about Canvas.save()? My execute time in the render is killing my performance.